# How do I view SCSS @warn and @debug directives in a Rails 3.1 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass

One of my favourite debugging features of SCSS is the @warn and @debug directives, which both aid with debugging. However, when I place either of these in my scss files in a Rails 3.1 project, they don't appear in the stdout (from running tail -f log/development.log)

Does anyone know whether it's possible to enable these so that Sprockets/Rails doesn't disable them, and I can view the output in the output stream.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't found how to enable them on the development log but can achieve the same thing by using sass --watch.

Here is my application.css.scss which mostly pulls other sass files using sass @import (not sprockets *=require. see [here](https://github.com/compass/compass-rails#notes-on-sprockets-directives) for why.) for shared variables/mixins/functions usage:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= depend_on projects
*/

@import "layout.css.scss";
@import "projects.css.scss";
```

Now suppose layout.css.scss has this variable:

```
$main-color:  #327B31;
```

I can get its value in file project.css.scss

```
@debug "Main color is:" $main-color;
@warn "Darker: " darken($main-color, 20%);
```

I open up a terminal window and point sass --watch at the main .scss file that pulls in the others

```bsh
$ sass --watch  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss --stop-on-error --trace
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
>>> Change detected to: /home/yuval/ws/books/railscasts/268-sass-basics/app/assets/stylesheets/projects.css.scss
app/assets/stylesheets/projects.css.scss:5 DEBUG: "Main color is:" #327b31
WARNING: "Darker: " #143214
         on line 6 of app/assets/stylesheets/projects.css.scss
         from line 16 of app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

  overwrite app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.css
```

`--stop-on-error`  is because errors tend to make sass --watch retry repeatedly which I don't want. `--trace` gives you a backtrace if an error happens.

So long as an error doesn't happen, this log will continue to refresh with each save.

I like this approach also because it's ruby/rails neutral (which it should be, it seems ) and so works with anything running sass.

Also, this works if you are using Compass on top of Sass.

Just activate compass in your application.css.scss file (or whichever .scss file):

```
@import "compass";
```

and then use ``compass watch```:

```bsh
$ compass watch app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss  --css-dir tmp/cache/
```

`--css-dir tmp/cache/` is to avoid compass watch creating .css files that override your .scss ones. I dump them into the cache with this.

Answer (score 3):

## Rails 5

If anyone comes here looking for this in Rails 5, you can simply add `@warn` directives to your stylesheets and the output will be printed to your console (you must be running `rails s`).

For example:

```
$main-color:  #327B31;
@warn "Main color is:" $main-color;
```

Will print this output to your console:

```
WARNING: "Main color is:" #f5f5f5
     on line 2 of /path/to/your/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
```

PS: As far as I can tell, this shows up in your console only - not in the logs.